# c++ compiler error using g++ -c: compiler recognizes a const string& as int

Tags: c++, int, g++, stdstring

i created a class Products that has the constructor

```
Product::Product(const int &num,const float &pr,const std::string &str):
number(num),price(pr),name(str)
{
}
```

i have the declaration in the header and an implementation in another source file
when i compile this using g++ -c i get an error:

```
g++ -c Product.cpp
Product.cpp:14: error: prototype for 'Product::Product(const int&, const float&, const std::string&)' does not match any in class 'Product'
Product.h:5: error: candidates are: Product::Product(const Product&)
Product.h:10: error:                 Product::Product(const int&, const float&, int)
```

why is this happening? why does the compiler replaces const std::string & with int?

Comment: Can we see the class declaration in Product.h? my guess is that the constructor declared there on line 10 has int as the last parameter

Comment: this is the declaration in Product.h

Comment: Product(const int &num,const float &pr,const std::string &str);

Comment: @ShahakShama , can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you forgot to `#include <string>` in your header, causing g++ to emit a questionable diagnostic that falls back on `int` for types it doesn't understand.

Comment: msvc defaults to int as well with a similar (and similarly questionable) error.

Comment: i did wrote #include<string> both in the header and the source file

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by deleting a file named Product.gch in the same folder
i don't know how it solved it but it did